# How can I create 2 Drupal web container with the same directory without multisite in DDEV?

Tags: ddev

For a project, I have to create 2 Drupal web container with the same directory but with different database.
But the 2 Website are not meant to be a Drupal multisite (I know, it's strange)....

In the [DDEV documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#confirming-docker-compose-configurations), it explain to use docker compose. But I can't make it work.

When I try, I have 2 possible error and I don't know how to correct it :

- If i define a explicit http_expose, I have the error the port is already in use (even the 9999)
- If i define a different http_expose, I will get a docker error who specify that mailpip and phpstatus are FAILED....

Can somebody show me how to get 2 web container with DDEV?

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDEV supports multiple databases just fine, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/#extra-databases

You do not need to create extra services or containers.

All you have to do is figure out where your settings.php will live, or have your settings.php change behavior for each of your sites.

I would recommend that path to you to start.

Comment: Hi rfay, Thank you for your answer <3 I already have figured where my settings.php will live and how to make it work for each web container. The database is not the problem :/ The problem come from the 2 web container :/ I don't understand how to make it work :/

Comment: As explained above, you don't need a separate container. You can use many techniques, either using normal name-resolution, which works just like multisite, or you can also do fancier nginx configuration to use a second docroot, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#multiple-docroots-in-nginx-advanced

If you are determined to run a second container, you'll do it with an additional service, and you'll mount the code into that service. But it's a very, very hard and unnecessary way to go.